# Unexpected behavior while typing an unicode character for a button text in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unicode

Instead of using plain text or drawing an icon for it, i wanted to place an unicode character as a button's text in Visual C# 2010 Express. The result is that its visible only if the button is enlarged enough but when i would scale it down to its intended size, the character goes out of the button's area during the process (it doesnt disappear suddenly, just moves out continuously while downscaling).

Here are the images showing the experienced behavior: [the initial enlarged button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAfET.jpg), [final size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvRrM.jpg)

Im newbie to programming, but i dont think its meant to work how it is working, provided that I didnt experience a problem with the characters found in ASCII. I couldn't find any setting to offset the character.

Im posting this in the hope of someone can clarify why this happens, how to resolve it without using an image instead. Or just lighten me up if if using unicode chars for such purposes is a bad habit because it causes further problems, incompatibility issues, whatever.

It behaves as if the character has free space around its actual line that resembles it. In character map i experience the same with other Cambria Math characters. The one im trying to use is U+21BB.

Comment: The font does not support that unicode codepoint then. try another font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like U+21BB, Clockwise Open Circle Clockwise.  It already behaves very poorly in the Charmap.exe applet when looking at it with Cambria Math selected.  The bounding rectangle looks pretty messed up, turning the glyph into a fleck of dust in the "Characters to copy" textbox.  Fonts can have bugs as well :)

Just pick another font, Cambria, Segoe UI Symbol and Lucida Sans Unicode behave properly.  This [web page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21bb/fontsupport.htm) is useful.